# where to store user info after login to swift ios app

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, keychain

I'm creating simple user login at the beginning of my app. After user submits correct username and password, my script from server should return some parameters which I should store in some sort of local database, and check for these parameters every time when new view appear/loads.

My questions are:

1) which type of local "database" should I use, which one is secure so no one else from "outside" can access it, because if someone could than he could set my logins by himself (keychains, user defaults etc.)?

2) which parameters should I return from server, which one of them are essentially from security when checking if user is logged in - I'm thinking of username and the token - if user is successfully logged in, than server script should create some type of token which will be stored in online database. Every time user makes some request from app to the server than token is checked, if it exists in app and if it exists in server database and if they are equal.

3) How should I check if user is logged in when new view is loading in the app - should I just check if variables exists (for example in Keychains) or should I connect to the server and check every time server database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for storing sensitive user data(password, api token, email) you should always use Keychain for this purpose.In other hand there is [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) also offer secure way to store your data.Its easy to use, you just need wrap data objects with realm base(Object) class and mark properties with dynamic attribute.For basic login system i think user name, email and api token good enough.But depends on api needs you can include here phone number, birthday etc.For checking user authorization I think validating api token good enough in most case.

There is also most secure techniques to improve data safety like keep database property names in keychain.Hashing sensitive data parts in api calls.Last thing you need use https for api communication.